# The meaning of "being mounted in horizontal frictionless bearings"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, terminology, torque, models

In the following scenario:

> In an Atwood's machine, there are 2 blocks. The pulley is mounted in horizontal frictionless bearings. When released from rest, the heavier block is observed to fall $x$m in $y$s. Calculate the rotational inertia of the pulley.

I'm confused with the meaning of "being mounted in horizontal frictionless bearings" and how that looks like in real life.

I solved the problem assuming the pulley system looks like the following, but I doubt its "pulley is mounted in horizontal frictionless bearings" as my system seems vertical to me.
[image]

Comment: just google images and atwoods machine

Comment: Yes, it is vertical and *pulley is mounted in horizontal frictionless bearings* means that the axis of the pulley is horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal frictionless bearing is an axle going into the paper, through the center of the circle.

We are looking at it from the side, but the pulley wheel will have some thickness.

It's like a bike wheel and somehow designed (with rolling bearings, or lots of oil) so there is no friction when it turns.

The details aren't too important for the question, it just wants you to ignore any energy losses generated due to friction.